# Как добавить дополнительные подразделы для сайта в поисковой выдаче гугла/яндекса?

Tags: seo

После вбивания в яндекс/google запрос про stackoverflow.com на первом месте мы видим собственно сам стак, а ниже дочерние ссылки.

Каким образом управлять выводом этих ссылок в поисковике?

[image: Картинка раз]

И каким образом можно вывести вот такое?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что не относится к программированию.

Answer (score 0):

1. Чтобы добавить контакты в поисковую выдачу, зарегистрируйтесь в [Google Мой Бизнес](https://www.google.com/business/).
2. Описанные вами "подразделы сайта" в поисковой выдаче, на самом деле называются [Ссылки сайта или (Sitelinks)](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=ru). Они формируются автоматически. Подробнее по ссылке выше. Вот выдержка из справка по Search Console:

> Мы показываем ссылки сайта только в том случае, если они могут
>   оказаться полезными. Если структура ресурса не позволяет нашим
>   алгоритмам выявить разделы, соответствующие запросу, ссылки показаны
>   не будут.
>
> В настоящее время ссылки добавляются автоматически. Соответствующие
>   алгоритмы постоянно совершенствуются, и в дальнейшем мы сможем
>   учитывать пожелания веб-мастеров. Однако есть ряд оптимальных методов,
>   позволяющих уже сейчас улучшить качество таких ссылок. Например, текст
>   внутренних ссылок и их описание в атрибуте alt должны быть
>   информативными, краткими и уникальными.

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтоб вывести адрес и телефон как на втором скриншоте, нужно зарегистрироваться в Яндекс справочнике. Так же сайт нужно добавить в Яндекс вебмастер и в вебмастере в "География сайта -> Адреса и организации" добавить адрес